# Gephi + Neo4J plugin + Mac (Java7)

Tags: java, macos, neo4j, java-7

I'm running on MacOSX(10.9.2) with Java7 installed. I want to use Gephi with the Neo4J plugin.

If I use Java7, Gephi won't start properly. I saw some discussions around that and the suggested "fix" was to downgrade to Java6. Unwillingly, I did so, but now the Neo4J plugin won't install as it requires Java7.

Any idea how do I get out of this loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

maybe this post on my blog could help you: I haven't used the Neo4j Gephi plugin (even if I just noticed it has been updated on April, 3 2014), in favour of an export + import approach. If you have jdk 7 installed, you can still point to jdk 6 by uncommenting jdkhome into gepghi.conf file.

See, http://inserpio.wordpress.com/2014/02/10/how-to-load-neo4art-graph-db-into-gephi/

Cheers,
Lorenzo